# Copy and Paste from Excel to a web asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am sure this question has been asked before. I am looking for some functionality to be able to copy a row from Excel and paste the result in a column in a web `<asp:GridView>`, first off is it possible. I have been scouring the web and have not managed to find something web related.

Answer (score 0):

> Here Mudassar Ahmed Khan has explained how to copy data from Excel
>   file or Clipboard and paste it to GridView in ASP.Net using C# and
>   VB.Net.
>
> We cannot paste the copied data from Excel file or Clipboard to
>   GridView and hence we need to paste the data to an ASP.Net Multiline
>   TextBox or TextArea and then populate GridView.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Copy-and-paste-data-from-Excel-Clipboard-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx